# Virtual template function visitor workaround with template derived classes

Tags: c++, templates, virtual

The problem is that `template <typename T> virtual void foo()` is illegal, and I'm trying to use the visitor pattern to workaround that (which is known to work in general).  However the derived classes of Base are template classes, and now I'm running into the virtual template problem within the visitor classes.  How to work around this?

```
struct Base {
//  template <typename T> virtual void foo() = 0;  // illegal
    virtual void foo (class Visitor& visitor) = 0;  // The attempted solution
};

template <typename D>
struct Derived : Base {
    virtual void foo (Visitor&) override;
};

struct Visitor {
    //template <typename D> // same problem again!
    virtual void visit (Derived<D>*) const = 0;
};

template <typename T, typename D>
struct FooVisitor : Visitor {
    virtual void visit (Derived<D>*) const override {/*Do whatever with T*/}
};

template <typename D>
void Derived<D>::foo (Visitor& visitor) {visitor.visit(this);}
```

With all solutions, let's assume there shall be about one hundred values for D, with new D classes being introduced constantly.  And each will use D in the same way.  For simplicity, let's assume each visit function will use D with

```
func<D>();
```

where

```
template <typename D> void Base::func();
```

is some helper function in Base.

Comment: what do you want to do in your template<typename T> virtual void foo(); ?

Comment: This is a generic problem isn't it?  The solution should be independent of the intention with T.  Perhaps there may be a special solution for certain goals with T, but there needs to be a general solution that works all the time.

Comment: how about making the template<typename T> foo() as non-virtual and then calling a virtual fooImpl() from foo()?

Comment: You need to do a downcast in `Derived<D>::foo()`.

Comment: Your `Visitor` should have `virtual void visit (Derived<D>*) const = 0;` for each `D` you expect.

Comment: @Jarod42.  Even if there are many, many values for D?  That is the only working solution?

Comment: @prestokeys: It is the way to do with *Visitor*

Comment: Where is your virtual destructor?

Comment: @prestokeys: No, it is not the only solution. As I said earlier, you need to downcast the visitor in `foo`. Whether that does exactly what you want, though, depends on exactly what you want.

Comment: @prestokeys: If you don't understand what I'm suggesting, i can post an answer.

Comment: @kec.  That would help, because the one solution that I do understand requires too much maintenance work due to the number of derived classes, and a lot of repeated code too due to the similar visit overrides.

Comment: @Jarod.  kec is coming up with a different approach, but also using Visitor.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution that might work. Note that the assumption here is that you only make invocations with the right type:

```
struct Base {
    virtual void foo(struct Visitor& visitor) = 0;
};

template <typename D>
struct Derived : Base {
    virtual void foo (Visitor&v) override;
};

struct Visitor {
    virtual ~Visitor() {} // Make this class polymorphic.
};

template <typename D>
struct Visitor_tmpl : public Visitor {
    virtual void visit (Derived<D>*) const {/*Do whatever with T*/}
};

template <typename T, typename D>
struct FooVisitor : Visitor_tmpl<D> {
    virtual void visit (Derived<D>*) const override {/*Do whatever with T*/}
};

template <typename D>
void Derived<D>::foo(Visitor&v) {
    // In this function, D has been bound now to a specific type, so we downcast.
    // It will throw an exception if not the right type.
    dynamic_cast<Visitor_tmpl<D> &>(v).visit(this);
}

int main() {
    Derived<int> d;
    FooVisitor<double, int> v;
    d.foo(v);
}
```

Comment: yes, that works, but the user has to define a visitor for each class it visits, which is cumbersome. Plus, when one uses `FooVisitor<double, float> v;` for the visit instead, the program crashes at runtime.

Comment: With all solutions, let's assume there shall be about one hundred values for D, with new D classes being introduced constantly.  And each will use T in the same way.

Comment: @davidhigh:  No classes need to be added. Of course you need to define an object of the right type, but you would need to do that regardless.

Comment: @prestokeys: This solution doesn't require any new classes to be added for new D. It does require a visitor be defined, but you always need that regardless.

Comment: @davidhigh: It doesn't crash per se, it throws an exception if the wrong type is used. The OP would have to provide more information about what should happen in such a case.

Comment: @kec: the difference to the code in my answer is (i) your code handles different implementations via specialization of `Visitor_tmpl<D>` for a ceratin `D`, whereas mine does it via overloading for the parameter `Derived<D>`. (ii) your code is going to be faster as there are no dynamic casts, but you pay this by a increased error-proneness.

Comment: @kec: I would suggest to add some function template `createVisitor` which takes the object-to-visit and returns the corresponding visitor. This reduces the probability of wrong usage.

Comment: @davidhigh: Yes, that could be done. Or, maybe they can be created in foo(). There are different options, depending.

Comment: @kec.  Ok I got it working with your solution.  But, the line in my program has `bluejay.startsMoving(MoveVisitor<Bird, Flying>());`, and I now realize since bluejay is of type Bird, ideally I don't want Bird in the template but only Flying (as opposed to, say, Walking), i.e. Bird being deduced somehow.  This way, startsMoving can be called in the base class Animal.  As it is right now, I cannot call 'startsMoving' in the base class since Bird needs to be stated.  So Bird needs to be a template of startsMoving instead, and thus deducible.  This changes everything doesn't it?

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution was mentioned by Jarod42, namely to specify all possibly occuring types. Usually, however, you want to give a standard implementation taking a `Base*` as well, and overload this only when required.

```
struct Type1 {};
//...
struct TypeN {};

struct Visitor
{
    virtual ~Visitor() {}

    virtual void visit (Base*) const = 0;
    virtual void visit (Derived<Type1>* d) const { visit(static_cast<Base*>(d)); };
    //...
    virtual void visit (Derived<TypeN>* d) const { visit(static_cast<Base*>(d)); };
};


struct FooVisitor : public Visitor
{
    virtual void visit (Base* base) const override
    {
        std::cout<<"visiting base class."<<std::endl;
    }

    //further definitions for those types that require a special implementation
    virtual void visit (Derived<TypeN>* d) const override
    {
        std::cout<<"visiting class of type Derived<TypeN>."<<std::endl;
    }
};
```

[DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/08a0b22e794ebb57)

---

**EDIT:** Here is another possibility using basic [double dispatch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_dispatch#C.2B.2B):

```
struct Visitor
{
    virtual ~Visitor() {}

    virtual void visit (Base*) const = 0;
};

struct FooVisitor : public Visitor
{
    virtual void visit (Base* base) const override
    {
        if(Derived<TypeN>* d = dynamic_cast<Derived<TypeN>*>(base))
        {
            std::cout<<"visiting class of type Derived<TypeN>."<<std::endl;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout<<"visiting base class."<<std::endl;
        }
    }
};
```

It releases you from declaring each possible variable type in the base class, but is probably less efficient than the previous solution.

This brute-force approach has some other disadvantages, which are collected [in chapter 11 of Alexandrescu's book](http://www.icodeguru.com/CPP/ModernCppDesign/0201704315_ch11lev1sec3.html). You can also read there how to overcome these disadvantages by using a static dispatcher. Basically there you just enter once the types you want to consider for dispatching, and let the code create the above logic.

[DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8d015a32b13de488)

Comment: FooVisitor itself has a template T, to be used with its visit functions, but it doesn't change the idea of the first solution.  The (first) solution is, however, hard to manage with so many derived classes (and new ones constantly being added).  Plus there is all the repeated code, because the implementation could otherwise be summed up easily using Type1, Type2, ... TypeN in the same way (but these cannot be represented as D here).  As for the second solution, there will be many, many if statements to check, right?

Comment: @prestokeys: I agree, I also find it hard to manage by now. I avoided your template parameter `T` because your code doesn't use it and I haven't understood its usage. Maybe you can clarify it? The repeated code, I guess, can be handled using one or more default implementation taking a `Base*` or a function template?

Comment: Yes, a helper function helper<D,T>() could be implemented from Base in all the visit functions, but each visit function will still need to call them up, e.g. `{helper<Type1,T>();}`, `{helper<Type2,T>();}`, ... `{helper<TypeN,T>();}` in the visit functions.  But at least that's an improvement.  Of course, `{helper<D,T>();}` is the ideal, but not possible.  Is multiple dispatch possible without using the visitor pattern?  My visitor solution attempt was only my attempt.

Comment: @davidhigh: It should also possible to auto-generate the dispatch code, but we probably need more info from the OP as to the best way to do it. For example, every instantiation of `Derived<D>` could have a static member whose ctor added an entry to map. Of course, then the OP needs to be careful about order of initialization, but it could be done.

Comment: For simplicity, let's assume each visit function will use T with `func<T>();`, where `template <typename T> void Base::func();` is some helper function in Base.  If D can be used, then `func<T,D>();` instead.

Comment: @prestokeys: Hm...you can't make a member template virtual, though.  I suspect that you want to do another downcast to some class, like Derived2<T>, then use multiple inheritance somewhere.

Comment: Actually, I'm probably oversimplyfing the assumption about T and D.  Perhaps just `func<D>();`.  Or maybe the solution being sought is too general to tackle and I have to start a new thread with more specifics about T and D.

Comment: It's not so much that it's too general to tackle, but rather that the design space is large, so it's hard to make the solution more specific without more details. For example, you haven't said what about my answer doesn't meet your requirements.

Comment: My implementation of T and D is a bit complex, though should be wrappable in a Base helper function.  I will try your solution with my program, if it runs into problems I will start a new thread with more specifics about T and D.  I really appreciate the help so far.  I'm sure this is a problem that others may run into too.